# Issues With Marketing cloud CloudPagesURL function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When I use CloudPagesURL function with no paramenters except the Id i don't have any issues.

**Case 1**

```
<p><a title="MyPage" href="%%=CloudPagesURL(232)=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">RSVP</a></p>
```

When I use CloudPagesURL with additional parameters other than ID i get

> **Error :** 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

**Case 2**

```
%%[
set @sk = _subscriberkey
]%%

<p><a title="MyPage" href="%%=CloudPagesURL(232,'sk',@sk )=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">RSVP</a></p>
```

Now this is where things get intresting if i wrap around the above code with `redirectto()` function everything works fine.

**Case 3**

```
%%[
set @sk = _subscriberkey
]%%


<p><a title="MyPage" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(232,'sk',@sk ))=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">RSVP</a></p>
```

**Question:** Is this behavior a bug in `CloudPagesURL` function or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm), CloudPagesUrl should always be wrapped in RedirectTo

```
<p><a title="MyPage" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(77777,foo,@bar))=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">Click to unsubscribe</a></p>
```

Any reason for you wanting to avoid this?

Comment: Honestly it doesn't explicitly say that! I never assumed that was a requirement as the rest of the examples were not wrapped.

Comment: The other examples on the page are not shown in a context of an ‘a href’-tag. They will print the CloudPageUrl in the text, but might not work in links. Again: I will always recommend it as best practice to wrap any URL, regular or CloudPageUrl in RedirectTo. I can’t see why you are trying to avoid this - if it proves to be working for you.

Comment: Thanks! My only complaint is the document could be more clearer!

Comment: I second that. You can also find several posts here on SFSE, where this issue is being discussed.

Comment: if I may - I think the part that is exceptionally confusing here is when you use Content Builder to create a link to a Cloud Page, Marketing Cloud itself doesn't use the RedirectTo()...
href="%%=CloudPagesURL(2588)=%%"

It seems strange to me that you should have to manually go in and wrap each link created this way with a "RedirectTo()".  Am I missing something here @LukasLunow? ;)